# How can I call a method on joined table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, scope, relation

I'm trying to create a scope for a frequently run query (i.e. Users with errors). The issue is that I have to join the User and Account tables then run a method on the account table to find out which User has errors. In other words, I need to find the Users that have Accounts which have error. I'm able to create this scope on the Account Model like this:

```
scope :with_errors -> {joins(:user).map(&:status).select{|status| status['code'] == :error}}
```

The problem is, I have to define this scope on Account because then I can run `map(&:status)` on the ActiveRecord::Relation that is returned from the join. So, my question is: is it possible to run a method on the "joined" table so that I can define this scope on my User model?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `status` *have* to be a method? It would be much easier (and faster) if you could use a database query e.g. Account.where(:status_code => 'error')

Comment: Unfortunately, `status` does have to be a method. We store the `user` in postgres and `status` in cassandra. So, I don't get to take advantage of all of the awesome rails helpers. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3?view=asciicast) gives an example of merging queries. In your case it would look like:

```
User.joins(:accounts).merge(Account.with_errors)
```

Comment: I decided to accept this answer because ... well ... it actually answers the question :) I think my setup is a bit too far off the mainstream to be supported by the rails helpers though.

Comment: ah, I forgot that you wanted a scope. Well, it would be trivial to write a scope that just does these 2, if you use it often.